# Validation on dynamically sized FieldList in WTForms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am creating a quiz webapp using Flask and WTForms in which the user is shown a quiz which they can answer. The questions for the quiz come from a DB and hence the form to let the users answer the quiz is dynamic. Here is how the form class looks like:

```
class QuizForm(FlaskForm):
    answers = FieldList(RadioField('Correct Answer', choices=CHOICES,
                                   validators=[DataRequired()]),
                        min_entries=0)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit your answers')
```

Before I serve the form, I append entries to the field list as follows:

```
questions = Question.query.all()
form = QuizForm()
for i, question in enumerate(questions):
    form.answers.append_entry()
    choices = [('1', question.option_a),
               ('2', question.option_b),
               ('3', question.option_c),
               ('4', question.option_d)]
    form.answers.entries[i].choices = choices
```

This works well and creates the form as I would expect. But, I am not able to get validation to work where I want to make sure the user has answered all questions. This is how I am currently validating the form:

```
questions = Question.query.all()
form = QuizForm(request.form)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() and len(form.answers.entries) == len(questions):
        # use form data
```

The problems I have are:

- I would ideally want the validation to work just using `form.validate()`.
- In the current approach, the values for `field.errors` are not set, and thus I can't show the user a message that a field is required right below the radio field containing the options for the question (using WTForms validation).

The full code can be seen at [github](https://github.com/amangup/coding-bootcamp/blob/master/lecture11/example_projects/quiz_webapp/quiz/quiz.py).

What is a good way to implement validation for this use case?

Comment: very similar to ones I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882720/, and another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048153/. Perhaps these give you ideas

Comment: @Attack68 - thanks for sharing those. The conclusion is that using setattr() to dynamically create the form class will solve the problem. Is that also a confirmation that validation won't work using FieldList?

Answer (score 1):

As commented further info in questions:  stackoverflow.com/questions/50882720 and stackoverflow.com/questions/51048153

Personally I would use the dynamic form method to assign a unique name to each `RadioField` required so that the result would be similar to, for example if the form was statically created:

```
class WebForm(FlaskForm):
    q_1 = RadioField('Q 1', validators=[InputRequired()], ...)
    q_2 = RadioField('Q 2', validators=[InputRequired()], ...)
```

Then the validators will definitely work as requested.

Failing that I suppose you could just write your own validator over your FieldList named `answers`. Here is an example of a custom validator catching an input field supposed to capture a full name and it breaks if it doesn't detect a space between names:

```
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError
class WebForm(FlaskForm):
    fullname = StringField('Input full name', validators=[])
    def validate_fullname(self, field):
        if ' ' not in field.data:
            raise ValidationError('Please give first and last name')
```

If you write your own validator on the `FieldList` you can perhaps loop through and check each has some data, but the more painful approach (in my opinion) is why I stated my preferred way of doing this.

Comment: So, if we want automatic validation, then using `set_attr` is the way to go to add a dynamic number of fields? Is there a use case when `append_entry()` is useful?

Comment: I've never come across append_entry and prefer setattr since it feels more basic pythonic. And in this case it allows automatic validation with the imported validators.